# What happens between Global.asax and MasterPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, currentuiculture

I am starting a multilanguage effort. In Global.asax.cs, method Application_BeginRequest(), a cookie is read and CurrentUICulture is set to `en-US`. However, in MyPage.aspx the value has surprisingly changed to `nl`.

Now this web site I inherited, and is medium-sized and has a fairly complex menu system. Also, it maintains a user table with a field for Preferred Language with values like `nl`, but I could not find (yet) in the code where this sets CurrentUICulture from that user table.

This is a page with a MasterPage, so I looked over there. I set a debug breakpoint in the first page event in MasterPage.Page_Init(), and in the Immediate Window I inspected System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name. Value is: 'nl'. I am completely puzzled.

My question is: what code can possibly execute between Global.asax.cs, Application_BeginRequest(), and MasterPage.Page_Init()?

Comment: have you checked anywhere where the CurrentUICulture property is used?

Comment: @mahlatse sure did. I did several global searches on such keywords, but could not solve my problem yet. If you cannot find the code by searching, you change to a debugging strategy, so I did. Strange thing is that the previous developer did some language switching, but without resource files, so he would not use CurrentUICulture at all. Still, its value is changing somewhere, hence my question.

Comment: if you set a breakpoint right after where ypu know it has changed and check the call stack, can you figure out what other method could modify  the value maybe?

Comment: @mahlatse No call stack. These are events. I can break in Global.asax  methods and inspect the Culture. I can break in MasterPage methods that fire after Global.asax methods, but then the call stack is just empty.

Comment: Many things happen between `Application_BeginRequest()` and page Init (where master page is also initialized). Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application_BeginRequest()` handler is the first step in the Asp.Net life cycle. Look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis

When a handler is executing (which is your page), it has its own life cycle:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

And this documentation says:

> Start
>
> In the start stage, page properties such as Request and Response are
>   set. At this stage, the page also determines whether the request is a
>   postback or a new request and sets the IsPostBack property. ***The page
>   also sets the UICulture property.***

When the available events are checked, we see:

> PreInit
>
> Raised ***after the start stage is complete*** and before the initialization
>   stage begins.

Therefore; it seems that the earliest stage you can change the `UICulture` is the `PreInit` stage. The most appropriate place however, is the `InitializeCulture` method which serves this specific purpose:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);

        HttpCookie languageCookie = Request.Cookies["lang"];
        if (languageCookie != null)
        {
            if (languageCookie.Value == "en")
            {
                base.Culture = base.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Name;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        // Or do it here. This is more appropriate.
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Despite being shared accross multiple pages, the culture information should not be set in the Master Page's event handlers, because as can be seen in the following trace output, when a page uses a master page, the master page is interpreted as a control of the page and the `Page_Load` event of this master page is executed during LoadControls() which is executed after the Page's `Page_Load` handler.

I also want to mention the tracing feature here. By enabling tracing, it is possible to see a lot of information about the page's execution process, its children, all the timings, headers etc.:

In the web.config file, under `<system.web>`:

```
<trace pageOutput="true" requestLimit="10" enabled="true" localOnly="true" traceMode="SortByTime" mostRecent="true"/>
```

Or read here for the `<system.webServer>` equivalent:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/tracing/

```
Control Tree
Control UniqueID    Type    Render Size Bytes (including children)  ViewState Size Bytes (excluding children)   ControlState Size Bytes (excluding children)
__Page  ASP.default_aspx    1104    0   0
    ctl00   ASP.masterpage_master   1104    0   0
        ctl00$ctl02 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    68  0   0
        ctl00$ctl00 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead 48  0   0
            ctl00$ctl01 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle    29  0   0
            ctl00$head  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder    6   0   0
                ctl00$head$ctl00    System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    6   0   0
        ctl00$ctl03 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    14  0   0
        form1   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm 954 0   0
            ctl00$ctl04 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    21  0   0
            ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder    291 0   0
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    198 0   0
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdn1  System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField   91  0   0
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    2   0   0
            ctl00$ctl05 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    18  0   0
        ctl00$ctl06 System.Web.UI.LiteralControl    20  0   0
```

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is that I should NOT set UICulture in the Application_BeginRequest handler (in Global.asax.cs), because that is too early, and my custom setting may be overwritten by some system setting.

Comment: What the documentation says is, if you set it before the Page's Start stage, it will be overwritten. You may set the Culture in BeginRequest if you need to use it through the steps from 1 to 13 (BeginRequest - ExecuteRequestHandler, exclusive) because ExecuteRequestHandler is where your page is executed.

Comment: Oh. Forgot that. The Page provides a virtual method for you to override, just for this purpose. `protected override void InitializeCulture()`

Comment: Your original answer fixed my posted question of setting the Culture. Your edit solved my next problem, that of activating the correct MyPage.aspx.XX.resx resource file. If the Culture is set in the MasterPage, the correct resource file is not loaded, probably because the MasterPage is actually just a control on the Page. I can't upvote your answer twice, but will upvote your comments instead :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really good to hear that. I am updating my answer once more to include trace information

Comment: haven-t tried this tracing yet, but am sure this will be useful sometime